# Distinct List of Contact_ID's with a MAX Call_date_time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a table that I need to gather data from that's formatted like so.

```
USER_id|| Reason_ID || CALLDATETIME||
18164564          4     2013-02-25 00:05:25
18164564          2     2013-02-24 00:06:30
18164286          8     2013-01-19 15:35:16
18164286          1     2013-02-18 12:31:59
```

There are other columns in the table, but I feel they do not matter for this particular example. So I need a list of all user_id's with the MAX (CALLDATETIME) but I only want 1 user_id for the report. I seem to always get a little confused when it comes to the distinct and the group by and order by syntax.

I took a look at an earlier thread but didn't quite understand how they got their results, and theirs was a MySQL example as well.

Comment: Is User_id the same as Contact_id?

Comment: Whoops yeah sorry it is, I'll change that.

Comment: If you get confused by `distinct` and `group by`, then basically forget about `distinct`.  It is really only necessary in `count(distinct)`.  It is a shorthand for grouping by all the columns in the `select` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the reason_ID, you could do the `GROUP BY` as a CTE and then join the reason_id later:

```
WITH max_cte AS
(
  select user_id, MAX(calldatetime) MaxCalldatetime
  from [tablename]
  group by user_id
)
SELECT max_cte.*, [tablename].reason_id
FROM max_cte
JOIN [tablename] 
  ON max_cte.user_id = [tablename].user_id
  AND max_cte.MaxCalldatetime = [tablename].Calldatetime
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
selct user_id, max(calldatetime) maxcalldatetime
from yourtable
where whatever
group by user_id
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work since I need the reason_ID included in the result set, and when I add that to the select it tells me I can't because it's not contained in an aggregate blah blah etc. Any ideas?

Comment: If you add reason_id to the select clause you also have to add it to the group by clause.  By the way, what do you mean by, "I only want 1 user_id for the report"?

Comment: I meant I only wanted distinct USER_ID's in the result set with the MAX CALLDATETIME so that I only got the most recent result_id for each user_id. Sorry about that. Glad that this community reads everything in a question to understand it correctly.

Comment: Jeff's answer will give you the correct data.  Be very careful how you display it because on it's own, it's misleading in that one might assume that the maxcalldatetime applied to every reason.